# One quote which boggle my mind

Tags: meaning, phrases

Browsing through one page I have stumbled upon a quote whose meaning I can't fully understand. This is the citation:

> If homosexuality is a disease, let's all call in queer to work: 'Hey can't work today, still queer'.

I can't come up with the meaning for '*call in queer to work*'. It would be helpful if someone could elucidate me its meaning.

Comment: It's a rephrasing of "call in sick to work," which means, call your place of employment on the phone, and say, "I'm sick; I won't be coming into work today."

Comment: I think this is General Reference, in that although many native speakers might do a "double-take" at this quirky one-off usage, the *meaning* itself will be obvious to them. There might be something interesting behind the idiomatic usage [call in/out sick](http://behindthegrammar.com/2009/08/call-in-sick-versus-call-out-sick-versus-call-off-sick/), but that's not what's being asked here.

Comment: @mic4ael You're seem to be questions of the sort that are ideally suited to the http://ell.stackexchange.com site. Are you not a native speaker of English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a joke on the claim that homosexuality is a disease. If you had the flu, you might call your boss and ask for the day off - we would say that you "called in sick to work". Similarly, if you had some chronic health condition - say chronic back pain - you might occasionally 'call in sick' to work to ask for the day off because you're experiencing high levels of pain that day. So the idea here is that if homosexuality is a disease, you could calling in sick as with any other disease. To emphasize this, the word 'sick' is replaced with 'queer', since this is the "disease" you are calling work about.

"Call in queer to work", then, means to ask for the day off from work due to having the "disease" homosexuality.

I believe the idea here is to take the concept of homosexuality as a disease to an extreme, which then demonstrates more intuitively the inappropriateness of this conceptualization of homosexuality.

Comment: I came here because i wanted to answer the question, but there is nothing left to add :) @mic4ael: you might want to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I can add that the form of argument is called [*reductio ad absurdum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum).

Comment: Thanks AndrewLeach, I was trying to remember that term but it escaped me for the moment.

Comment: What seems to be taken as read here - and is no doubt understood by many readers, but may not be understood by some who are learning English - is that *queers* was a derogatory term used to refer to homosexuals.

Comment: By the way, on tangent, the argument is ineffective because people have chronic diseases that don't prevent them from getting a job and working, then they cannot use that to call in sick. For example, "I can't come to work, I have diabetes" doesn't really fly, even though diabetes is in fact a disease. If you have some acute episode, or medical appointment, related to the illness, that is different, of course, but not in general.

Comment: @TrevorD: _was?_

Comment: @AndrewLazarus [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/queer?showCookiePolicy=true) describes the usage as "taboo". At least in the UK, one would be very unwise to use it in any (semi-)public arena.